# adding new points in a scatter plot

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to add new points to the scatter plot in a async manner. For that, there is an api in scatter plot "addpoint" that adds newly sent data to the chart without refreshing the scatter plot. The code used in this is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Height Versus Weight of 507 Individuals by Gender'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Heinz  2003'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Height (cm)'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weight (kg)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 5,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                        }
                    }
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Female',
            color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
            data: [[161.2, 51.6], [167.5, 59.0], [159.5, 49.2], [157.0, 63.0], [155.8, 53.6],
                ]

        }, {
            name: 'Male',
            color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
            data: [[174.0, 65.6], [175.3, 71.8], [193.5, 80.7], [186.5, 72.6], [187.2, 78.8],
                ]
        }]
    }); 

    function requestData() {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts(); 
        var points = [
                {
                    x: Math.random() * 100, 
                    y:Math.random() * 80 
                }
            ]
        var series = chart.series[0];    
        var data;
        chart.series[1].addPoint([Math.random() * 100,Math.random() * 80]);     
        // call it again after one second
        setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
    }
    requestData();      
    });
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

  </body>
   </html>
```

The fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/anirbankundu/T8GT3/1/

Can anyone let me know if there is any possible way to add an array of points instead of adding each point step by step. I will be fetching around 1000 points for each call and the total number of points can go above 100K

Thanks,
Anirban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `chart.series[1].data` to get the current serie data and then use `chart.series[1].setData` to update it's data.

```
function requestData() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
        serie = chart.series[1];

    // get serie data
    var data = serie.data;

    // append points to data
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        data.push([
            Math.random() * 100,
            Math.random() * 80
        ]);
    }

    // update serie data
    serie.setData(data);
}
```

You can see it working [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/T8GT3/2/).

**Update** - Append points to the current data

```
function requestData() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    // append points to data
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        chart.series[1].addPoint([
            Math.random() * 100,
            Math.random() * 80
        ], false);
    }

    chart.redraw();
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T8GT3/3/)

Comment: This is not appending the existing data. Instead it keeps on adding new data - i.e. refreshing the previously retrieved data. What I need is to append to the existing data.

Comment: @Anirban So this case you can use `addPoint` with the second parameter `false`. What this will do ? Will add a new point without render the chart. So this way you can append how many points you want and then redraw the chart.

Comment: This looks good, just that you are calling add point method in a loop. I am aware of this. Anyways, thank you very much for taking the pain to solve the issue